# each of recyclerview item is streached on whole screen and I didn't get why

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

so I'm trying to display recyclerview, but every time is using whole scree, but more acurate is if I'd say that it's using space as needed but there are extra space between items

1.contennt-main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">



  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/rec"
     android:scrollbars="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

2.activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

3.booking.xml, items in recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="booking name"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:text="User name"
        android:textSize="10sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="time"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to change some height but it didn't work so what should I do?

Comment: Add screenshot of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Booking.xml, to your LinearLayout(root), change to

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="**wrap_content**"

Answer (score 0):

In booking.xml

change

```
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

with

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```